How does Elastic cache cluster connectivity works in AWS?
I am having a VPC (172.31.0.0/16) and 3 public subnets.I have created a redis cluster and have got a DNS for that cluster. I having a ec2 machine in subnet-1. Now i want to understand the connectivity between the cluster and the ec2.

where are the cluster nodes located, within my VPC or separately?

if within VPC, how it is ensured that the ip address(es) given to cluster nodes does not conflict with exisitng ip address of ec2 machines?
if outside of vpc, how is the ec2 machine able to connect to cluster as i can see no vpc endpoint configuration.



